# django/python convert string which represents a python dictionary into a dictionary object

Tags: python, django

I have a string which represents a python dictionary returned from a db table e.g.

```
{'name': 'John', 'email': 'test@test.com'}
```

where `{'name': 'John', 'email': 'test@test.com'}` is returned as a string from the db

I then have a function which receives a dictionary as **kwargs e.g.

```
def print_details(*args, **kwargs):
    name = kwargs.pop('name', None)
    email = kwargs.pop('email', None)

    print "%s - %s " % (name, email)
```

I want to do

```
dict = DB return value
print_details(dict)
```

but I don't know how to convert the string dict into a python dictionary

I am using Django but if there is no way in Django then Python would obviously work as well

Comment: "string dict into a python dictionary"?  Did you try `eval()`?  What was wrong with that?

Comment: @S.Lott: There are several things wrong with `eval`, not only in OP's case ;)

Comment: A database containing strings that represent Python dicts? That sounds like it's breaking all kinds of rules of database normalization...

Comment: @delnan: several things wrong with `eval()`?  Do tell.

Comment: @S.Lott: It's slow, can easily lead to security problems or hard-to-debug errors, therefore requies exsessive validation (i.e. not hard to use properly even when warranted), and of course it's usually the wrong (too powerful) tool for the job.

Comment: @delnan: The data in the database has security problems and hard-to-debug errors?  Really?  Do we have evidence of that in the question?  I missed it.

Comment: @S.Lott: Generally speaking. But depending on how the data is generated, it could be vulnurable to that as well.

Comment: @delnan: "Generally speaking"?  I would think that the answer should focus on the question.  There isn't any evidence of security problems and hard-to-debug errors in the data as present in the database.

Comment: @S.Lott: As you wish. In that case, two severe problems with `eval` remain and there are alternatives that don't have them but work just as well. Problem solved, don't you think?

Comment: @delnan: Two severe problems with `eval()` remain?  Which two?  There seem to be no problems with `eval()` in the context of this particular question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is a very restricted, safer `eval` that only evals literals (e.g. dicts, tuple or list literal containing string, int, float, ... literals).

A JSON parser would work as well for an even more restricted subset (bools are different, `null` instead of `None`, no tuples, perhaps even more). Again, [the standard library can do this](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) (and there are third party solutions for older Python versions).